# Same instance sharing with multiple requests in Java (OOP)

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I have one class whose single instance needs to be used by multiple classes in Java. I found two solutions for the same:
1. Pass the instance as method parameters
2. Use Static factory

My question is if I used static factory, how can I differentiate the incoming requests when I am using the static method. I want to avoid the 1st solution as there are many classes that are going to use this instance. Also, recommend the best design if other than mentioned above.

Code Example:

```
 class MyClass{


        Map<String, List<String>> myMap=new ConcurrentHashMap();

           public static void addToMap(String key, String value){
              if(myMap.containsKey(key)){
                  List<String> stringList=myMap.get(key);
                 stringList.add(value);
               }
               else{
                 myMap.put(key,value);
               }
           }
    }
```

I want to perform this add method at many places while program execution for eg:

Method addEmployee():

```
if(employeeName==null){
   MyClass.addToMap("ER101", "Name Error");
}
Method insertInDB():
catch(SQLException e){
   MyClass.addToMap("SQL", "Error Occurred in DB Operation");
}
```

Thanks

Comment: just do a Singleton?

Comment: @hetalashar Your question needs more clarification. Can you post some example code to explain your thoughts? What exactly do you mean when you say *Use Static factory* and *how can I differentiate the incoming requests when I am using the static method*?

Comment: Can't use singleton... There are going to be multiple request.

Comment: and what should the problem be here?

Comment: You can share a singleton (or any other instance) across multiple requests as long as it's thread safe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of ways to make the same instance of a class available to different callers such as threads or requests.

One of the easiest things you can do is create a singleton as shown above.  The problem with singletons is that there can only ever be one of them, as they are generally set up to enforce that there is a single instance of them.

Better is to create your instance, and pass it to the things that need it.  If you're creating a web application or similar, you can use a Dependency Injection framework such as SpringFramework to achieve this.

Injecting your instance where it is needed will mean it will be easier to replace this instance with a dummy instance for testing, and during testing you'll be able to create many instances of this class configured in different ways to test.

Answer (score 0):

As ***12dollar*** says: Use the Singleton Design Pattern, and ask for that instance to the Singleton Class:

```
public class ClassicSingleton {
   private static ClassicSingleton instance = null;
   protected ClassicSingleton() {
      // Exists only to defeat instantiation.
   }
   public static ClassicSingleton getInstance() {
      if(instance == null) {
         instance = new ClassicSingleton();
      }
      return instance;
   }
}
```

Then you could call `getInstance()`.

Answer (score 0):

The best design would be to make your class as Singleton class.
For your usage i think you can follow the below steps,

- make your constructor as private.
- then, have a static function inside that class to return the instantiated  object of your class.
- you can have your own if(classobj==nul) check to verify if its already instantiated or not(only on first call it will be null , further calls it wont be null) and return the object.

Cheers :)